# SMTP mail send with ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, office365, port

I am trying to figure out why I can't send a simple mail with attachment using a **office365** account, I don't if my code has something wrong or configuration from account is missing, please help with the code:

code is:

```
protected void sentmail(string sb)
{ 
    using (var msg = new MailMessage())
    {
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("myaccount@company.cl));
        msg.From = new MailAddress("botmail@company.cl");
        msg.ReplyToList.Add("botmail@company.cl");
        msg.Subject = "Test Mail";
        msg.Body = sb.ToString();
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        var client = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.office365.com", //it worked on testmail
            Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("botmail@company.cl, "password"),
            Port = 25,
            EnableSsl = true
        };
        client.Send(msg);

    }
}
```

Error on sending is:

```
5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [SC1PR80CA0082.lamprd80.prod.outlook.com]
```

Comment: office365 mail = one giant thunder c...  I have had a similar issue,  let me dig out my code

Comment: i edited just now! please help!

Comment: Your error handling is not good. Don't write your function to return an `object`. You should let the exceptions bubble up to where they can be handled rather than passing them around functionally. Remove those try/catch blocks, and don't have your method return a boolean. Just have it be `void`. If it doesn't throw an exception, you can assume it completed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This is production code that I have in place that will do the sending for you

```
using (var msg = new MailMessage())
        {
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(userName));
            msg.From = new MailAddress(userName);
            msg.ReplyToList.Add(model.EmailAddress);
            msg.Subject = "Message from the Web";
            msg.Body = sb.ToString();
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            var client = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "xxxmydomainxxx-co-uk.mail.protection.outlook.com",
                Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password),
                Port = 25,
                EnableSsl = true
            };

            // You can use Port 25 if 587 is blocked 
            try
            {
                client.Send(msg);
                return true;
            }
            catch (SmtpException smtpEx)
            {
                return smtpEx;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: you have to add it inside the void function i assume?
 msg.ReplyToList.Add(model.EmailAddress); //whats this line for?

Comment: the reply to list is so the receiver can reply to the person who is sending the email.  So, if youre on a web form, and sending to the host \ site owner, it would be sent via the office 365 account, and if you wanted to reply, rather than have to copy and paste the email address from the email, you can just hit reply

Comment: You can also have this as a void or as part of an object. I have it as a static object so that I can return a true on the send or an smtp exception or general exception back to my calling object so that it can be error handled accordingly should anything go wrong

Comment: i used your code on my edit, since the problem doenst seem to be the code itself should i mark it as an answer? thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: Tried code after being unblocked from ports, still cant send mail

Comment: i had similar issues, whats the exceptions youre getting?

Comment: take a look at this, I had to follow something similar \ if not follow this to get the sending sorted as well as the above code https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712724(v=exchg.150).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It works without attachment?

Try add the host in credentials:

```
credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(MAIL_CREDENTIALS_EMAIL, PASS_CREDENTIALS_EMAIL, HOST_EMAIL);
```